# Can't load facebook js sdk from Chrome extension

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to use facebook sj sdk in a Chrome extension.
Im doing this on my extension init:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        // init the FB JS SDK
        FB.init({
            appId: 'APP_ID', // App ID from the App Dashboard
            //channelUrl : '//www.example.com/', // Channel File for x-domain communication
            status: true, // check the login status upon init?
            cookie: true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
        });

        // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
        console.log(FB);

    };

    // Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
    (function(d, debug) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement('script');
        js.id = id;
        js.async = true;
        js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document, /*debug*/false));
```

I'm getting this error:

**Refused to load the script 'http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".**

I have the permissiosn in manifest set to `http://*/`. How can I load the sdk from an extension?

Answer (score 6):

This is because you are trying to load an external script from your Chrome extension.  For security reasons to prevent cross-site-scripting you need a special permission in your `manifest.json` file.

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://connect.facebook.net; object-src 'self'"
```

Make sure you use https:// instead of http://.